# Block common dos attacks

Tags: debian, firewall, iptables

I have been searching for some basic IPTABLES protection agains Syn attacks and floods I have found thise commands:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp ! --syn -m state --state NEW -j DROP //syn protect
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL ALL -j DROP //xmas packets protect
```

Will they really help to stop these kind of attacks ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, They are filters that block specific types of (D)DOS attacks, so yes. They are by no means a panacea however, as there are many ways to DOS/DDOS a server, at the IP layer or higher.

There are filters for several other forms of DOS attack here: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-iptables-10-how-to-block-common-attack.html

I recommend you look into Bucket filtering, as an approach to rate-limiting packets of certain types. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Token_bucket

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaky_bucket

More info on Rate limiting in IPTables here: 
http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-limit-linux-syn-attacks.html